# Which URL scheme would be better in this situation?

Tags: web-services, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm building a web service which handles items for different countries. So far a request is something like `example.com/item.php?country=us&id=1234`

The idea is to rewrite these uri using friendly names. I'm thinking about two possible choices:

1. us.example.com/1234
2. example.com/us/1234

My preference is for #1 but I was wondering what would be the pros and cons of each. Admin access to the server wouldn't be an issue btw.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution (us.example.com/...) would require working with DNS entries and host headers. potentially you would have to make a different site for each country (depending on your hosting platform).

Your second approach (example.com/us/...) is simpler, and probably requires less work and maintenance.